# how to know when fetchProviders() completed execution?

Tags: swift, firebase, callback, firebase-authentication

I am making a feature for my app to allow users to register using their emails. I am using Firebase and I would like to make use of `fetchProviders()` from the Firebase API.

This is what I have so far:

```
func submitEmail() {
    var errorMessage = [String()]

    Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: email) { (providers, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let providers = providers {
            errorMessage.append("Error - email already in use")
            print(errorMessage) // prints "Error - email already in use"
        }
    }

print(errorMessage) // prints []

if errorMessage.count > 0 {
    /* show alert */
}
```

Now, my problem here is clear; Callback functions run **asynchronously** and thus `errorMessage.count` will equal `0` when we get to the *if* statement, simply because the callback function is running on another thread.

**Desired Behaviour:**
I would like my UI Thread to hang wait until the callback function is called, so that if an email is already in the database, it can be detected. I would like to find an elegant way of doing it (not sure what good practice is in this case). Yes, I could put a timer in there to guess when the callback is done executing but that would be a pretty horrible way of doing it (since the execution time of this callback depends on the connection to Firebase).

Comment: What if you call that fetchProviders method in a Dispatchqueue.main block?

Comment: You can simply do whatever you need to do from inside the completion handler. You already figured out you can only access values returned from async methods from inside their completion handler, so what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching the providers may require a call to the backend servers. Since this may take some time, it happens asynchronously. Once the data is available, your completion handler is called. This means that data about the providers is only available *inside* the completion handler. So if you need the providers or the error message, your code will have to be inside that completion handler.

For example:

func submitEmail() {
    var errorMessage = [String()]

```
Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: email) { (providers, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else if let providers = providers {
        errorMessage.append("Error - email already in use")
        print(errorMessage) // prints "Error - email already in use"
    }
    if errorMessage.count > 0 {
        /* show alert */
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this won't work because after `fetchProviders()` (and still within `submit()`), I am pushing the next stage of the registration process (where the user chooses a password). If I place the `if` statement within the completion handler, the observed behaviour will be that the user is taken right to the next screen before the email is checked.

Comment: The logic should always be the same: the code that requires the data should be (invoked from) inside the completion handler where the data is available.